# Verify Java bytecode generated by ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM (http://asm.ow2.org/index.html) to instrument some java classes. After instrumentation, I will obtain new .class files. However, sometimes when I run the new .class files, JVM will throw java.lang.VerifyError.

I wonder whether there are some ways to verify the generated java bytecode before running them (or loading them to JVM).

Thanks :)

Comment: See https://blogs.oracle.com/dns/entry/yet_another_offline_java_bytecode

Comment: And https://github.com/krestenkrab/jvm-verifier